# Merging 3 separate commands into one that re-encodes a video, extracts a thumbnail, delete original and rename new video in subdirectories

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, find, command-line-interface

I am trying to execute a find bash command to process hundreds of video files that are all named `video-original.mp4` but are in subdirectories of a parent directory.

Here's an example of the directory structure:

```
videos
├── 01a
│   └── video-original.mp4
├── 01b
│   └── video-original.mp4
├── 02a
│   └── video-original.mp4
├── 02b
│   └── video-original.mp4
├── 03a
│   └── video-original.mp4
└── 03b
    └── video-original.mp4
```

I am using the following command:

```
find ./ -name 'video-original.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -profile:v high -acodec aac -movflags faststart video.mp4 -hide_banner' {} \;
```

The problem I am having is that it is saving the file `video.mp4` in the parent `videos` directory, instead of in the subdirectory next to the original `video-original.mp4`

Afterwards, I want to delete the file `video-original.mp4`. Currently, my process entails waiting for all the videos to be reencoded, and then once complete, issuing a separate command to delete the file `video-original.mp4`:

```
find ./ -name 'video-original.mp4' -exec bash -c 'rm -rf "$0"' {} \;
```

And my final step would be to extract a screenshot of the new `video.mp4` at 10 seconds and save it as `thumbnail.jpg`. Again, I am currently doing that as a separate step that I execute after the previous two steps are completed.

```
find ./ -name 'video.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg' {} \;
```

What I would like to do is combine these three steps into a single command so the end result will be:

```
videos
├── 01a
│   ├── thumbnail.jpg
│   └── video.mp4
├── 01b
│   ├── thumbnail.jpg
│   └── video.mp4
├── 02a
│   ├── thumbnail.jpg
│   └── video.mp4
├── 02b
│   ├── thumbnail.jpg
│   └── video.mp4
├── 03a
│   ├── thumbnail.jpg
│   └── video.mp4
└── 03b
    ├── thumbnail.jpg
    └── video.mp4
```

Finally, it would be great to save that as a bash script and include it in my path in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` as an executable so I could just issue the command `reencode` and it would run. Would be even better if the input file could have any video file, for example, `random_name.mp4` or `random_name.mov` or `random_name.webm`, basically any video file (but skipping `video.mp4` at the encoding step).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there might be two issues one being the path `./` — so maybe try using:

```
find . -name ...
```

Otherwise the path is translated as `.//file`, which doesn't seem correct.

The next issue is that since you are running the `find` command from the parent directory anything called with `-exec` is going to be output there. Instead we'll want to use `-execdir` since that will handle everything within the directory of the file it found. Since you want to create a command out of it we'll make it into a bash function which you can then add you to `~/.bash_profile` or wherever you prefer to setup your environment.

```
encode () { export target=$2 ; find . -name "*$1*" \
! -name "$target" -execdir bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 \
-preset veryslow -profile:v high -acodec aac -movflags faststart "$target" \
-hide_banner -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg' {} \; \
-execdir bash -c 'rm -f "$0"' {} \; ; }
```

Basically what this does is wrap the entire `find` command within a bash function which you can call from the command-line (once added to your profile, etc.):

```
$ encode mp4 video.mp4
          |      |
          |      |___ target file (encode will also skip this file)
          |
          |___ recursively encode files matching this extension
```

To summarize, the `encode` function wraps the `find` command, which in-turn searches recursively for any files matching the extension you select as argument one. The `target` (arg two) is the filename or output file to be saved. After the encoding is complete the original file that the `target` was encoded from is removed. If a file matches the extension you select and is within the same directory as the `target` then the matching file will be encoded to the `target` file (overwriting it); regardless of this the `target` file is always skipped and never encoded.