# Loop recursively for specific extension and subfolders

Tags: bash, recursion, ffmpeg

I have been trying to convert flac to m4a, I have the below script that does the job but it is not recursive:

```
for f in *.flac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f"  -vf "crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" -c:a alac "${f%.flac}.m4a"
done
```

For recursive, I did try several ways but none worked, here is what I tried
(space on file name is the problem here)

```
for f in `find . $PWD -iname *.flac`; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f"  -vf "crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" -c:a alac "${f%.flac}.m4a"
done
```

and this

```
find . -type f -iname "*.flac" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        echo "$line"
        ffmpeg -i "$line"  -vf "crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" -c:a alac "${f%.flac}.m4a"; done   
    done
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second try fails because of word splitting: the output of `find` gets split up.

Your last try would work, but there is one `done` too many, and you use `$f` in `"${f%.flac}.m4a"` where it should be `${line%.flac}.m4a"`.

I'd use a glob instead (requires `shopt -s globstar`):

```
for fname in **/*.flac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$fname"  -vf "crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" \
        -c:a alac "${fname%.flac}.m4a"
done
```

This searches the whole subtree of the current directory without the need for `find`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Bash 4.0 or newer

Comment: works beautifully, none of my methods work (after correcting the mistakes that you pointed here), it just hangs after the first encoding (Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>])

Answer (score 3):

Using the `-execdir` option with `find`:

```
find . -name "*.flac" -execdir bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0"  -vf \
"crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" -c:a alac "${0%.flac}.m4a"' {} \;
```

Recursively matches/re-encodes `.flac` files  as `.m4a` and saves them in the same directory. Using `-exec` instead of `-execdir` any re-encoded files would be saved to the location the command above is being executed from — which likely isn't what you would want.

> The `-execdir` primary is identical to the `-exec` primary with the
>                exception that utility will be executed from the directory that
>                holds the current file.

This solution works nicely, especially if your version of bash doesn't include `shopt`'s `globstar`.

↳ [Another example of ffmpeg re-encoding using `find` and `-execdir`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657024/merging-3-separate-commands-into-one-that-re-encodes-a-video-extracts-a-thumbna/41657131#41657131). (more complex)