# Sample frames of video

Tags: macos, opencv, video, python-3.5, subsampling

I'm looking for a way in OS X/Python3.5 to take an `.avi` video file, subsample every 100th frame, and combine those frames into its own video.

In my particular case the video is 30 seconds at 20fps, so the new video would only be 6 frames long (I want to do this for multiple videos, then combine them all together later).

I installed `opencv`, but am having trouble finding documentation on how to do this. I could also use a different library if it's easier.

Comment: Maybe consider using `ffmpeg` with subprocess; I think `OpenCV` requires it anyway, so just cut out the middleman...

Comment: I'm open to anything but I have to do this for tens of thousands of videos spanning hundreds of subdirectories. Does `ffmpeg` have any way to automate this or would it be one video at a time? Wanted to use python because I have some experience with the `os` library.

Comment: In `bash` you could have it recursively traverse directories with the help of `find`. Is there a reason why you need `Python`? And yes, `ffmpeg` can be easily automated with the right scripting skill. One such example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41657131/499581

Comment: Not really I just thought otherwise I'd have to learn multiple different tools that I'm not experienced with like bash/regex/ffmpeg and I'm under a bit of a time constraint

Comment: It's not that difficult actually, and sticking with `Bash` simplifies the process in my opinion since you aren't reliant on any other languages and their idiosyncrasies.I write up a quick answer... although I have a couple of questions first. 1) How many videos do you plan on creating 2) Once you've subsampled the videos you want to combine them into one 3) Do you want to remove the captured images once the video is created from them?

Comment: I have about 35K videos with directory structure schoolname(20)/month(3)/day(31)  where some of these directories are empty. I'd like to subsample all the videos in each of these 1,860 folders to make one video for each folder and then I don't need the actual frames. If the created videos are named like `schoolname_month_date.avi` then they could all be placed in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ffmpeg` and creating a couple of custom `bash` functions:

```
subsample () { export target=$2 ; find . -type f -name "*$1*" \
              -execdir bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "${0}" -vf "select=not(mod(n\,100))" \
              -vsync vfr -q:v 2 "${target}/${0}_%03d.png"' {} \; \
              -execdir bash -c 'ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -i "${target}/${0}_%03d.png" \
              -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${target}/clip_${0}"' {} \; \
              ; rm -f ${target}/*$1_*.png ;
             }

subconcat () { export target=$2 ; ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i \
              <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" ./clip_*.${1}) -copytb 1 \
              -c copy ${2}/combined_output.${1} ; 
             }
```

Save the functions in your `~/.bash_profile`.

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

***synopsis***

```
subsample|subconcat <ext> <target path>
```

(eg. pwd `/path/movies`):

```
subsample avi /path/to/output
```

**`subsample`** - recursively find any `avi` and combine every 100th frame into a new video @ target.

**`subconcat`** - combines all `clip_*.ext` videos of designated extension  @ target.

> It's presumed you'll want to adjust the `ffmpeg` settings to suit you,
>   although the examples above should give you a general idea of what is possible using only ffmpeg and bash find.

Comment: Thanks this worked great running each function separately. I edited the path for the 2nd function so piping would work because it tried to go into `/./vid.avi`

Comment: You're welcome! I wasn't certain whether or not it was going to do everything you wanted, so I'm really glad it worked for you. The way it deals with paths could definitely be improved, (but fairly easy to do though generally). The most difficult part to understand is usually the arcane commands `ffmpeg` uses...

Comment: Generally as a rule I `cd` into the directory where I want to start from and then run the command — that way you'll know that it's working in the right place and not somewhere undesirable. Using certain commands with `find` can easily spell disaster if you're not paying attention of where it's starting from...

Answer (score 2):

Simple logic with [needed functions](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter):

```
make 
  VideoCapture
  VideoWriter

do
   fr = cv.GrabFrame until file end
   if 0 = (counter % 100)
        WriteFrame(writer, fr)
```

[Python examples](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: Thanks although with my limited experience this may take me a very very long time if at all. Very first thing I tried, `cv2.VideoWriter.open()`: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'open'`

Comment: @Jake I have no experience with Python implementation, so added example page to my answer

Comment: That was Neat and Clean :) @MBo